# Assigning char value in one array to char value in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof, strlen

Sounds easy, but I've got a bug and I'm not sure  what's causing it?

```
nopunccount = 0;
char *ra = new char[sizeof(npa)];
while (nopunccount <= strlen(npa)) {
    ra[nopunccount] = npa[strlen(npa) - nopunccount]; 
    nopunccount++;
}
```

ra never gets a value into it and I have verified that npa has char values to provide within the nopunccount range.

Any help is appreciated // :)

Comment: Now is `npa` declared? What is `strlen(npa)`? Please post working code.

Comment: char *npa = new char[sizeof(str)];
str is declared as a param to the function as (char *str)

Comment: That’s a problem: `sizeof(str)` will yield wrong results (i.e. it will yield the size of a pointer, *not* the length of the string!).

Comment: Good point, what would you suggest?

Comment: Always use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` when working with strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nopunccount`starts as 0, so in the first iteration of the loop the character assigned to `ra[0]` is `npa[strlen(npa)]`. This is the terminating `'\0'` of that string. So the resulting string in `ra` starts with a `'\0'` and is therefore considered to be ending at that first byte by the usual string functions.

Comment: Groovy, didn't know that you can't have a null value mid string, but that makes perfect sense. Thanks :)

Comment: A null-terminated string can't have a null in the middle of the string by definition, because a null ends the string...

Answer (score 2):

What does the declaration of `npa` look like?  If it is a pointer, `sizeof(npa)` will be the size of a pointer, rather than the allocated size.  If these are zero-terminated strings (also known as "C strings"), then use `strlen`, not `sizeof`.  If these aren't strings, you need to track how much you allocated in a separate variable.

I have some other critiques of this code, possibly unrelated to your problem.

```
while (nopunccount <= strlen(npa)) {
```

`strlen` is an O(n) operation.  This code will traverse the string `npa` in every loop iteration.  It's best to only compute the length once.

```
   ra[nopunccount] = npa[strlen(npa) - nopunccount];
```

Same problem here.